# Get the difference between two types of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following two arrays:

**Array1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6012
    [1] => 7792
)
```

**Array 2**

```
Array
(
    [6012] => Array
        (
            [title] => COIN Group           
            [nid] => 6012            
        )

    [7792] => Array
        (
            [title] => fdsfsdafdsa
            [nid] => 7792            
        )

    [4689] => Array
        (
            [title] => General Group            
            [nid] => 4689           
        )

    [6784] => Array
        (
            [title] => Invitation to join the group Applied Economics for Managers 
            [nid] => 6784           
        )

)
```

I need to compare these two arrays and find the difference in values between array 1 and array 2. My output needs to look like this exactly:

```
Array
(

   [4689] => Array
        (
            [title] => General Group            
            [nid] => 4689           
        )

    [6784] => Array
        (
            [title] => Invitation to join the group Applied Economics for Managers 
            [nid] => 6784           
        )

)
```

How can this be done using PHP?

Comment: $groups = array_keys($user->groups); and i get the difference also using array_diff... but my o/p is not what i need. it looks like Array
(
    [0] => 4689
    [1] => 6984
). I need with all the values what it has in array 2

Answer (score 1):

```
$compare_array1 = array_values($array1);
$compare_array2 = array_keys($array2);

$diff_keys = array_diff($compare_array2, $compare_array1);

$result = array();

foreach ($diff_keys as $key)
    $result[$key] = $array2[$key];
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
result = array();

foreach array2 as key => value {
    if (in_array(key, array1) {
        result[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function diffArrays($array1,$array2){
    foreach($array1 as $key)
        unset($array2[$key];
    return $array2;
}
```

or

```
function diffArrays2($array1,$array2){
    return array_diff_key($array2,array_flip($array1));
```